# How to Open Telnet Console in post section of Kickstart

Tags: ssh, centos7, telnet, kickstart

I want to configure external VxWork based device in post section of kickstart file, this accept telnet based commands. I found following

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
send -- "terminal length 0\r"
expect "*?EDR*"
spawn timeout 600 ssh -o admin@x.x.x.x
match_max 1000
send -- "copy tftp x.x.x.x my.ini\r"
expect "*?AAA*"
exit
```

Any other alternative?

Comment: Interesting. I’m sure you may have python options too. Is there any reason you don’t want to use the example you have?

Comment: I haven't evaluate python option. Above solution working for me already but good to evaluate other possibilities.